# JUnit test case to insert records into database

Tags: java, junit

I want to write a JUnit test case to insert records into my Oracle database. But I want to insert only if the records don't exist. I already have a method in my dao class that is doing the insert, which I will be calling in my JUnit test case. Any idea on how to do it only if a record doesn't exist? Is there something in JUnit like there is assertNotNull, assertTrue that does insert only if the record doesn't exist?

Comment: I am not sure what you are actually trying to do. Are you writing a UnitTest for testing your insert-method? Or do you need some code that prepares the database tables (e.g. truncating tables)?

Answer (score 1):

I would check in my unit test if the record exists, if it doesn't exists I would insert it and verify (assert) that the record is inserted.

Pseudo code:

```
@Test
public void testInsert(){
Record record = ... // creation of the record
assertNull(recordDao.checkRecordExists(record)) // fails if there is a record
recordDao.insertRecord(record);
assertEquals(record, recordDao.fetchRecord(record)); // fetch record by Id and assert it eguals the inserted record.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make two tests: one where the record does not exist, and assert that it was inserted.

Make another where the record does exist, and assert that the insert did not happen.